# Software Center not opening showing error

Tags: software-center

I am a Linux mint 14 user. I am not able to open the software center.

```
tusharmakkar08@tusharmakkar08-Satellite-C660 ~ $ software-center
ERROR:root:DebFileApplication import
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from debfile import DebFileApplication, DebFileOpenError
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/debfile.py", line 25, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application, AppDetails
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 27, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 172, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ImportError: No module named linuxmint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 128, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 53, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.db.application import Application
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/application.py", line 27, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.distro
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 197, in <module>
    distro_instance = _get_distro()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/distro/__init__.py", line 172, in _get_distro
    module = __import__(distro_module_name, globals(), locals(), [], -1)
ImportError: No module named linuxmint
```

Please help me out

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Most questions about non-official Ubuntu derivatives are classified as *off-topic*. This isn't the correct Stack Exchange site to ask questions about non-official Ubuntu distributions (see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq)). However, it would be on-topic at [the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help:

`sudo apt-get remove --purge software-center`

Then:

`sudo apt-get install software-center`

in the end:

`sudo software-center`

and give us the output.